# How can I check if a user came via Google Adwords (e.g. by using the __utm* coockie)?

Tags: php, cookies, google-ads-api

How can I check in PHP if a user comes via an adwords campaign? Some time ago, there was a cookie "utmcsr" that used to hold this information, but how can I extract this information nowadays?

Comment: Ah: one solution is using an extra parameter in the destination url (e.g. using http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867&rd=1), however what if I do not want to use this? Is there still a way by only using the information at hand in the cookies?

Answer (score 4):

Two things you have to do:

1. Enable Auto-Tagging in your AdWords Account
   https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1752125?hl=en
2. Now on your website you can get the HTTP_REFERER ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) and
   search the string for "clid". If the referer contains the string
   "clid" it comes from AdWords. q= even gives you the keyword.